# TFS Power tools Migrate doesn't actually migrate

Tags: tfs, migrate, tfs-power-tools, unshelve

I would like to migrate a shelveset from one branch to another. Here is my command:

tfpt unshelve MigrateShelf /migrate /source:"$/Code/OldBranch/Source" /target:"$/Code/NewBranch/Source"

When I execute it, I the window pops up, but it is still unshelving into OldBranch.

I see this question

[tfpt migrate for TFS doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870323/tfpt-migrate-for-tfs-doesnt-do-anything)

and it looks like he has the same question, but he accepted an answer, then complained that it didn't solve his issue?

Comment: So, I have discovered that the branch that the shelf is originally from has been deleted, but I don't think that is causing this issue.

Comment: If I try to continue with the migration anyway, I get messages saying "newer version exists in source control", but I think that that is related to the fact that the branch has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem.

After investigating, the command, I come to conclusion that the command is correct, it only the issue in the path_name. there must be some typo error in command.

When the path is incorrect, its unshelving the changes in the same branch.

Command:
tfpt unshelve /migrate "shelve_name";user_name /source:"$/Sourcepath" /target:"$/targetpath" /nobackup

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Well seeing as how this was a year and a half ago, I no longer have access to that source any longer, but I'm pretty sure I double checked the target path. Is that what you meant by path_name?

Comment: yes, I had also the same problem, and finalyy seen that the path_name is incorrect(have some extra spacing issue). Above command works fine for me after deleting the extra space.

Comment: As another follow-up, to get your actual branch path, right-click the branch in the Source Explorer -> Advanced -> Properties.  Once I did that it worked.